# Conditional Inference Trees meaning of statistical values

Tags: r, tree, inference

I've run a Conditional Inference Trees analysis with R that I built following the examples in [here](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html). The code that I'm running is as follows:

```
fit <- ctree(Status~Amount.Converted + Campaign.Type + Region,
         data = d_c)
```

What I don't understand is what the statistics mean when I look at the 'fit' value. I tried looking at the help and the file [here](http://statmath.wu-wien.ac.at/~zeileis/papers/Hothorn+Hornik+Zeileis-2006.pdf), but I cannot make sense of what the criterion and statistic means. Here is an example of the output:

```
> fit

     Conditional inference tree with 10 terminal nodes

Response:  Status 
Inputs:  Amount.Converted, Campaign.Type, Region 
Number of observations:  5822 

1) Region == {FR, IT, N. Africa, Rest of Africa, Turkey}; criterion = 1, statistic = 261.91
  2) Amount.Converted <= 12486.57481; criterion = 1, statistic = 42.64
    3) Region == {IT, N. Africa, Rest of Africa, Turkey}; criterion = 1, statistic = 50.451
      4) Region == {N. Africa, Rest of Africa}; criterion = 0.99, statistic = 13.683
        5)*  weights = 66 
      4) Region == {IT, Turkey}
        6)*  weights = 843 
    3) Region == {FR}
      7)*  weights = 908 
  2) Amount.Converted > 12486.57481
    8) Amount.Converted <= 39800; criterion = 0.998, statistic = 11.339
      9)*  weights = 9 
    8) Amount.Converted > 39800
      10)*  weights = 11 
1) Region == {Benelux, cis, East EU, DE, SP, Mid. East, Nordics, UK}
  11) Campaign.Type == {Rental}; criterion = 1, statistic = 49.144
    12) Region == {Benelux, UK}; criterion = 1, statistic = 22.721
      13)*  weights = 25 
    12) Region == {DE, SP}
      14)*  weights = 37 
  11) Campaign.Type == {Retail}
    15) Region == {Benelux, East EU, SP, Mid. East}; criterion = 1, statistic = 37.237
      16) Amount.Converted <= 2734.76; criterion = 0.986, statistic = 8.023
        17)*  weights = 1179 
      16) Amount.Converted > 2734.76
        18)*  weights = 311 
    15) Region == {cis, DE, Nordics, UK}
      19)*  weights = 2433
```

Can someone explain what the criterion and statistic mean. The weights I understand that are the number of samples that fall on one node.